# I can't print "enter" in Mips

Tags: mips, qtspim

I'm converting C code to Mips code

The C code is

```
int main(void) {
int i;
int data [10] = { 10, -2, 5, 22, 99, 0, -5, 8, 30, 7};
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", data[i]);
       }
  return 0;
 }
```

my Mips code is

```
.data
    data: .space 10

    enter: .asciiz "\n"
.text
.globl main
main:
addi $s0, $zero, 10
add $t0, $zero, $zero
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, -2
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 5
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 22
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 99
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 0
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, -5
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 8
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 30
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $s0, $zero, 7
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $s0, data($t0)

addi $t0, $zero, 0
Loop: slti $t1, $t0, 10
      beq $t1, $zero, Exit
      mul $t2, $t0, 4

      li $v0, 1
      lw $a0, data($t2)
      syscall

          li $v0, 4
      la $a0, enter
      syscall

      addi $t0, $t0, 1
      j Loop
Exit:




end:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

s1 is for saving a value.
t0 is for index
t1 is a flag for slt
t1 multiply 4 is t2

you should just focus on

```
          li $v0, 4
      la $a0, enter
      syscall
```

it prints
10-2522990-58307

dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

plz help me dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: I use Window10!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't reserved enough memory for your `data` array. `.space 10` reserves 10 *bytes* of memory, but you're trying to store 10 *words* (40 bytes). So you end up overwriting the newline character.

If you change the declaration to `data: .space 40` you should get the expected output.

Comment: oh thank you so much!!! why didn't I check that... but I have a question. How could I initialize the array in the first place with 10 bytes of memory?

Comment: and I have to initialize the array in the data segment not in main. could you tell me how to do that or anything I can refer to?

Comment: Hey Micahel, and how do you get more than one input integers at once? I had posted another question about it. you can check it out